# How do I add 1 to a variable each time it replaces a specific string

Tags: powershell

What I am trying to do is add 1 to $b each time it replaces the word hello with modal$b so it should look like modal1, modal2 etc.

```
 $a=1
$b=1
$original_file = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\2.txt'
$destination_file =  'C:\Users\me\Desktop\4.txt'
do { 
(Get-Content $original_file)  | ForEach-Object  {
  $_  -replace "hello", "modal$b"` 

    } | add-Content $destination_file

    $a++
}
until ($a -gt 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
thanks,
Sarash

Comment: Your `do` loop, could you explain what is it for? Seems like `ForEach-Object` should be enough to go through the file's lines

Comment: I was messing around with html and this does work but each time it replaces hello with modal$b it changes it to modal1 for every instance in that file. I am trying to figure out how to add 1 to $b each time it replaces hello. Instead of it replacing it with modal1 for every instance I was trying to replace it with modal1 modal2 etc.

Comment: @Sarash Which version of PowerShell are you using? In version >6.1 you can do: `$counts = @{ b = 1 }; @(Get-Content $original_file) -replace "hello",{"modal$(($counts['b']++))"}`

Comment: The version I have is 5.1.22000.282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with just a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=The%20ForEach%2DObject%20cmdlet%20performs,construct%20a%20ForEach%2DObject%20command.) loop, there doesn't seem to be a need for the `Do` loop. Following what you already have, you can increase your variable like below.

```
$original_file = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\2.txt'
$destination_file = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\4.txt'
$b = 0
Get-Content $original_file | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'hello', "modal$(($b++))"
} | Out-File $destination_file
```

The following would work too, using a [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) with a *Script Block*, this example would require to use the `-Raw` switch on [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#example-6--get-raw-content). It's important to note that using this method, the pattern is case sensitive (i.e.: **'Hello' will not match 'hello'**), if you want it to be case-insensitive you could use the `(?i)` flag: `'(?i)hello'`.

```
[ref]$ref = 0
[regex]::Replace((Get-Content $original_file -Raw), 'hello', {
    "modal$(($ref.Value++))"
}) | Out-File $destination_file
```

[Replacement with a script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-a-script-block) was [implemented](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/6029) in **PowerShell 6 (Core)**, thanks [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) for the hard work :)

Above example, if you have PS Core, would be replaced by:

```
[ref]$ref = 0
(Get-Content $original_file -Raw) -replace 'hello', {
    "modal$(($ref.Value++))"
} | Out-File $destination_file
```

And there wouldn't be a need for the `(?i)` flag since `-replace` is already case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you that did exactly what I wanted it to.

Comment: Oh, nice. I never saw a regex: replace making use of a scriptblock just like that. TIL

Comment: @Sarash If you are satisfied, You can accept his answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @SagePourpre glad you could learn something new, I did learn it too by just being around here :)